# What is the underlying math needed to answer the following questions:

Tags: percentage, arithmetic

Some background: I was applying for an entry level business analyst position, and I was completely lost with some of these questions. These questions were from the practice test. I'm not sure how I did on the actual test, but if I were to encounter this in future, I would like to be prepared. Any idea what I should be studying? Statistics? Economics? The questions start below and should be answered using the chart.

If the inflation indices were reset to 100 in the the 3rd quarter, what would be the fourth quarter inflation index for food.

If the average family food basket costs 100 Euros at 2nd Quarter prices, how much would it cost at 3rd Quarter prices?

Which Quarter saw the largest percentage increase in Earnings through inflation?

If the inflation indices were reset at 100 again at the 3rd Quarter, what would be the 4th Quarter inflation for Foods?

[image]

I want to thank anyone who answered, and hope to be a part of the community moving forward. This is my first question, so if there are any links on question "Do's and Dont's" or "How To's", those will also be appreciated.

Comment: To answer these questions you need: (1) some basic economics, business jargon and (2) be able to change units (eg. like changing units from feet to inches). IMHO the question also uses imprecise terminology. I would relabel it European *price* indices. Inflation is the *change* in the price level, not the price level itself. The question would also be a better fit for economics.stackexchange.com. It really isn't about statistics.

Comment: Lookup [price index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_index).

Comment: Ok, perfect. The price index link looks very promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere this question says "inflation index" it should instead say [price index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_index).

Let $X_t$ be the price of some basket of food items at time $t$. Inflation $\pi_t$ (from $t-1$ to $t$) is given by the percent change in the price index from $t-1$ to $t$.

$$ \pi_t = \frac{X_t - X_{t-1}}{X_{t-1}}$$

$\pi_t$ is inflation. $X_t$ is the price index (or price level).

1) If the food price index were reset to 100 in the 3rd quarter, what would be the 4th quarter price index for food?

- Let $Y_t = \frac{100}{X_3} X_t $. Now $Y_t$ is a rescaled version of the price index $X_t$ that is rescaled so $Y_3 = 100$.
- What is $Y_4$?

2) If the average family food basket costs 100 Euros at 2nd Quarter prices, how much would it cost at 3rd Quarter prices?

$$ \require{cancel}100 \cancel{\text{ Q2 euros}} \cdot \frac{95 {\text{  Q3 euros}}}{97.5 \cancel{\text{ Q2 euros}}} = $$

Comment: So the solution to the first question was something along the lines of (94/95)*100. The second question was (97.5-95)/95. You then multiplied this by 100 to obtain the actual change which is 2.63. You take the original price and subtract the change, 100 - 2.63 ~ 97.

Comment: @Nahuatl_19650 You're right on the first question. For the second question, think about 2nd quarter euros, 3rd quarter euros, etc... as different units. In the same way 100cm = 1 meter, 95 Q3 euros = 97.5 Q2 euros in the case of food.  A basket of food costs 100 Q2 euros. So you can change the units to Q3 euros by multiplying by the conversion factor $\frac{95 {\text{  Q3 euros}}}{97.5\text{ Q2 euros}}$

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand your method. If I multiply 100 * 95 = 9,500 and then divide by 97.5, equals 97.44. If I do it the way I presented on my original comment, (97.5-95)/95 = 0.0263. Multiply by 100, equals 2.63. 100 - 2.63 = 97.37. I'm getting this from a different thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192007/understand-simple-problem-on-inflation you may check it out if you'd like. I would much rather use your method than the one on the thread.

Comment: @Nahuatl_19650 I added an answer over there that corrects the accepted answer. Use my method.